# How to load a synth style in java

Tags: java, xml, load, styles, synth

I am experimenting with synth styles and i came across the following problem for which a haven't found an answer yet after quite some research. I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<synth>
    <style id="button">
        <state>
            <color value="blue" type="BACKGROUND"/>
            <color value="yellow" type="FOREGROUND"/>
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="button" type="region" key="Button"/>
</synth>
```

and the following java code to load that xml file as a SynthLookAndFeel object

```
private void initializeStyle() {
    SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
    try {
        laf.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Style.xml"), this.getClass());
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
    } catch (ParseException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When i try to run this code i get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must supply an InputStream, StyleFactory and Class or URL
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this are more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a good example in [Advanced Synth](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-synth/).

You can see in the example that:

```
SynthLookAndFeel synth = new SynthLookAndFeel();
synth.load(SynthFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("demo.xml"), SynthFrame.class);
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(synth);
```

And `demo.xml` lives in  `demo.synth` package, the same of `SynthFrame` class, where this XML contains some images:

```
<imageIcon id="check_off" path="images/checkbox_off.png"/>
```

Where `checkbox_off.png` lives in `demo.synth.images` package.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: This helps, but my user interface is not showing the right style.

Comment: Load the styles before start the frame. You can use the method `EventQueue.invokeAndWait()` for load the styles and `EventQueue.invokeLater()` for start the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Main Calss :

> SynthLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = new SynthLookAndFeel();
>   lookAndFeel.load(TestRApp.class.getResourceAsStream(synthFile),
>   TestRApp.class); UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);

synth.xml file

```
<style id="panelStyle">
    <imagePainter method="panelBackground" path="images/main-bg.png" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" stretch="true"/>
</style>
<bind style="panelStyle" type="region" key="Panel"/>
```